# IE8 is not started on Windows7 from Selenium (webdriver) on Python code

Tags: python, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, selenium, webdriver

My code is simple

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie()
```

IE8 is not started. No exceptions, no errors.

> OS - Windows 7 Interprise 32x bit
>
> browser IE8.0.7600.16385
>
> Python 2.7 Selenium-2.3.0-py2.7

Why IE8 is not started? Where can be problem?

Problem does not exist on Windows 7 64x bit version.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You must have all security zones same value. Following is the text from [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
The browser zoom level must be set to 100% so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This option had checked. Unfortunately it does not help.

Comment: Are you running the tests as administrator? I am using Java binding and it is working fine for me..Did you also try with the latest selenium 2.4 release?

Comment: Yes. I'm running as adm. selenium 2.4 is used too. :(

Comment: I use this test on real Win7 box (same configuration) without problem. IE8 starts...

Comment: What do you mean by real win7 box? You also say below does that mean you are having issue with Win7 32 bit? "Problem does not exist on Windows 7 64x bit version."

Comment: Sorry. I have real Win7 64bit box and virtual boxes (Win7 64bit and Win7 32bit). Python + WebDriver don't start IE8 on both virtual boxes.

Answer (score -1):

just download and copy IEDriverServer.exe in C:\IEDriver\ folder ,

And in Internet option under security tab Enable protected mode for all zones.

than it should work.